# Como abreviar palavras em PHP?

Tags: php, string

Possuo informações comuns como nome de pessoas e endereços, e preciso que elas contenham no máximo 30 caracteres sem cortar palavras.

Exemplo:

```
'Avenida Natalino João Brescansin' => 'Av. Natalino J. Brescansin'
'Joaquim Rossafa Nascimento filho' => 'Joaquim Rossafa N. filho'
'Rua José Jesualdo Garcia Pessoa'  => 'R. José Jesualdo G. Pessoa'
```

Como posso fazer isso em PHP?

Existe algum método ou expressão regular para resolver este problema?

Comment: Sim é possível, desde que existe uma regra ou criterio, nos casos de `rua`=>`r` e `avenida`=>`av` é tranquilo e qual é a regra para os demais?

Comment: Pensei em fazer desta forma, porém não consegui encontrar regras ou critérios suficientes para atender a todos os requisitos. Por exemplo, nessa situação tenho endereços e nomes de pessoas, supomos que tenhamos o nome 'Carlos Eduardo João Bruno Rodrigues', se o nome 'João' for um nome do meio, poderá ser abreviado, caso contrário, não. Entende?

Comment: As palavras precisam ser abreviadas de tal forma que não percam sentido.

Comment: interessante essa questão,  vamos por partes:
1 - defina a quantidade de palavras na frase;
2 - defina o tamanho ideal para a frase;
3 - separe a frase em palavras usando split() ou outro procedimento para tal;
4 - com o lista de palavras da frase, vc pode, em um laço, ou pesquisar nela pela maior depois da primeira ou determinar um indice para determinar quais das palavras essa lista abreviar e pegar a primera letra de cada palavra nessa lista e adicionar ". " nelas  até a frase atingir o tamanho desejado pelo que voce determinou como tamanho ideal;
precisando tamos ai

Comment: Eu não lembro quase nada de PHP, então nem vou arriscar postar uma resposta. Mas basicamente vc já teve muita ajuda. Como o colega @rray disse, você precisa estabelecer as regras. Algumas são óbvias como as que ele menciona, outras vc precisa criar. Para os átomos do nome, uma regra possível para fazer a abreviação poderia ser: o nome é curto (menor do que x caracteres) e não é o primeiro ou o último. Se vc *precisar* abreviar de qualquer forma, talvez a parte do "nome é curto" poderia ser trocada para "é o mais curto dentre os existentes".

Comment: A resposra do @rray é correta, mas é preciso tomar cuidado, caso seja criada uma lista de palavras passíveis de abreviação note que rua deveria ser r. mas crua não npode ser abreviada para cr. abraço

Comment: Como já mencionado, você deve primeiro estabelecer todas as regras de abreviação. Feito isso poste essas regras na sua questão e as pessoas estarão aptas a responder com objetividade.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implementei uma *função genérica* com alguns pormenores (como no caso da abreviação do último elemento de `$list` - logo se vê que não fica muito bonita a abreviação, mas brincando um pouco com o código você melhora isso). O código está bem comentado, então não vou explicar demais em texto. Qualquer coisa, pergunta nos comentários.

A saída do programa:

```
$ ./abrev.php
26: Av. Natalino J. Brescansin
24: Joaquim Rossafa N. Filho
27: R. José Jesualdo G. Pessoa
36: Il. Sr. Dr. Jabulani J. Joniscleyson
16: Praça da Igreja
42: Pç. da Igreja N. S. M. d. J. C. N. Senhor
```

O código:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

/* tamanho máximo da string */
$max_length = 30;

$table = array(
    "Avenida" => "Av.",
    "Rua"   => "R.",
    "Praça" => "Pç.",
    "Ilustríssimo" => "Il.",
    "Senhor" => "Sr.",
    "Senhora" => "Sra.",
    "Doutor" => "Dr.");

$list = array(
    "Avenida Natalino João Brescansin",
    "Joaquim Rossafa Nascimento Filho",
    "Rua José Jesualdo Garcia Pessoa",
    "Ilustríssimo Senhor Doutor Jabulani Jurango Joniscleyson",
    "Praça da Igreja",
    "Praça da Igreja Nossa Senhora Mãe de Jesus Cristo Nosso Senhor");

/* MAIN: aqui é feita a abreviação dos itens */
foreach($list as &$str) {
    if(strlen($str) >= $max_length) 
        abrev($str);

    printf("%d: %s\n", strlen($str), $str);
}

/* &$str
 *
 * Significa que o parametro será uma referência, não um cópia. As alterações
 * que eu fizer em $str dentro de abrev() são aplicadas à $str "verdadeira".
 */
function abrev(&$str)
{
    /* referencias globais */
    global $table;  
    global $max_length;


    /* verifica entradas tabuladas,
     *
     * a contagem com preg_match é usada como offset no proximo
     * loop.
     */
    $matches = 0;
    foreach($table as $k => $v) {
        /* /$k/i 
         * testa a chave (as definições completas) na string.
         * preg_replace funciona na mesma base.
         */
        if(preg_match("/$k/i", $str)) {
            $matches++;
            $str = preg_replace("/$k/i", $v, $str, 1);
        }
    }

    /* aqui separa-se a string em palavras */
    $s = explode(" ", $str);

    /*        Rua José Jesualdo Garcia Pessoa
     * pos  : 0   1    2        3      4
     *
     * matches = 1
     * count() = 5
     *
     * inicio
     * i = 5 - 2 = 3 (começa no Garcia, penultimo nome)
     *
     * fim
     * i >= $matches + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2
     * (segunda palavra depois da ultima abreviação tabelada)
     */
    for($i = count($s) - 2; $i >= $matches + 1; $i--) {
        /* \.$ testa se o ultimo caractere da string é um ponto.
         * Se for, significa que já está abreviado, e se já é uma
         * palavra abreviada, saímos do loop.
         */
        if(preg_match("/\.$/", $s[$i])) break;

        /* unset é importante pra 'n' não ficar com lixo */
        unset($n);

        /* a primeira letra da palavra atual */
        $n[] = $s[$i][0];
        $n[] = ".";

        /* substituimos s[i] pela versão abreviada */
        $s[$i] = implode("", $n);

        /* testa o tamanho total da string */
        if(full_length($s) <= $max_length) break;

    }

    /* junta tudo pra "retornar"... o parâmetro é por referência, 
     * não por cópia
     */
    $str = implode(" ", $s);
}

/* Nada elegante... *Nada* eficiente... mas quebra o galho.
 *
 * Provavelmente tem como fazer a troca de uma palavra por sua primeira letra
 * seguida por um ponto usando expressões regulares.
 */
function full_length(array $s)
{
    $s = implode(" ", $s);
    return strlen($s);
}

?>
```

Normalmente sou contra postar códigos prontos, mas como esse está longe de ser bom para produção... Vai ter que trabalhar nele pra melhorar a eficiência, especialmente se for usar em alguma *engine* de conversão de dados.

Answer (score 3):

Vamos lá meus caros,

quando vamos abreviar nomes próprios no PHP a tarefa é simples, devemos nos atentar que aqui no Brasil os nomes que devem ser mantidos por extenso se possível devem ser o primeiro nome e o último sobrenome. Imaginem o seguinte nome:

**Antonio Fernades Coutinho**

Um agradável resultado para a abreviação desse caso seria:

**Antonio F. Coutinho**

Omitir os nomes intermediários nem sempre pode ser visto com maus olhos:

**Antonio Coutinho**

Mas vou colocar abaixo a solução que contempla a primeira abreviação que mantem apenas a inicial do nome abreviado seguido de um ponto para indicar abreviação.

```
//String com nome a ser abreviado
$name = "Antonio Fernandes Coutinho";

//como os nomes são separados por espaço em branco então vamos criar o array
//a partir dos espaços
$split_name = explode(" ",$name);


//so vamos abreviar o nome se 
//ele tiver pelo menos 2 sobrenomes
if(count($split_name) > 2){     

    //esse for inicia a partir da segunda
    // posição do array para o 
    //primeiro nome ser desconsiderado
    for($i=1;(count($split_name) - 1) > $i; $i++){

        //claro que como existem dos|de|da|das 
        //(Cristina DOS Santos) podemos 
        //omitir ou exibir sem abrevirar 
        //essas preposições, aqui no 
        //caso eu as mantenho sem alteração
        if(strlen($split_name[$i]) > 3){

            //aqui será feito a abreviação com apenas
            //a inicial da palavra a ser abreviada
            //seguida de ponto
            $split_name[$i] = substr($split_name[$i],0,1).".";  
        }       
    }   
}   

//aqui será impresso o nome resultante com a junção 
//do array em favor de se obter uma string colando as posições
//do array com espaços em branco!
echo implode(" ",$split_name);

// Antonio F. Coutinho
```

Para abreviar tipos de Logradouros (Rua, Avenida, Praça, ...) pode-se criar um array com os valores brutos "Avenida" como chave e "Av." como valor dessa chave, e abreviar quando isso for encontrado na string, com uma leve mudança no código acima é possível fazer isso.

Fica claro que se a situação for mais complexa onde se precisa higienizar um conjunto elevado de combinações limitadas considere usar expressão regular.

Abraço

Answer (score 2):

Chapa, se tem um banco com 20k de registro cria um Script em Python que dá um replace nas palavra caso ultrapassem o 30 caracteres e posteriormente popule uma tabela com as equivalência baseadas no id.
Tipo, cria um Dicionário ['Avenida':'Av', 'Rua': 'R.', etc], então dá um select * no banco e itere com um loop for sobre a lista que retornou, jogue um if no for que pede o len da string e dê os replaces do dicionário caso passe-se os 30 chars, crie um dicionário básico e coloque pra fatiar string com [0:x] caso seu dicionário não faça o trabalho completo. Depois que tiver as duas tabelas no seu banco é teta linkar no php. Particularmente não conheço nada mais poderoso pra se processar String do que o Python.

Answer (score 0):

No caso de nomes de pessoas, por exemplo: Fulando de Tal, abrevia-se por Fulando T., usando um simples script em PHP como esse debaixo:

```
  $name = "Fulano de Tal";
  $array = array('da','de','di','do','du','das','des','dis','dos','dus','la','le','li','lo','lu','las','los','les');
  $n = explode(" ", $name);
  if (count($n) > 1) {
      $er = array_diff($n, $array);
      $eco = current($er);
      $eco2 = next($er);
      echo $eco;
      echo " ";
      echo substr($eco2,0,1).".";

  }else{
      echo $name;
  }
```